# Flutter TextField controller.clear() will invoke onChanged multiple times

Tags: flutter

here is the code :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'test',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('test'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            onChanged: (text){
              print('>>>>>>>>>>flutter onChanged text=${text} _controller.text=${_controller.text}');
              if(text.length==4){
                _controller.clear();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the log
[image]

after invoke controler.clear(),the onChange() was invoked. And the value didn`t change

Comment: The value in the TextField gets cleared. i tested and it worked. what exactly is the issue here?

Comment: ok, cleared at last , It`s true. The real question is : why the onChange method will be invoked several times, after I cleared the value? and the return value looks like not been reset

Comment: I only get this behavior on iOS. On Android it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`_controller.text = "";`

instead of `_controller.clear();`

Comment: the same result , the onChange will be invoked 2 to 5 times